# How do you reference a table with a key value that is numeric in Lua?

Tags: lua

The output for the below script is:

```
AD[1] = [variable not found]
AD['2'] = bar
```

How can I modify the function getfield to return a value for v for both cases?

```
function getfield (f)
  local v = _G    
  for w in string.gfind(f, "[%w_]+") do
    v = v[w]
  end
 return v
end

AD = {[1] = 'foo', ['2'] = 'bar'}
data = {"AD[1]","AD['2']"}

for i,line in ipairs(data) do
  s = getfield(line)
  if s then
        print(line .. " = " .. s)
  else 
    print(line .. " = [variable not found]")
  end
end
```

**UPDATE:**
I'm 90% sure, this is going to work for me:

```
function getfield (f)
  local v = _G    
    for w in string.gfind(f, "['%w_]+") do
      if (string.find(w,"['%a_]")==nil) then
        w = loadstring('return '..w)()
      else 
        w = string.gsub(w, "'", "") 
      end
      v=v[w]
  end
  return v
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens to work

```
function getfield (f)
  local v = _G    
  for w in string.gfind(f, "['%w_]+") do
    local x = loadstring('return '..w)()
    print(w,x)
    v = v[x] or v[w]
  end
 return v
end

AD = {[1] = 'foo', ['2'] = 'bar'}
data = {"AD[1]","AD['2']"}

for i,line in ipairs(data) do
  s = getfield(line)
  if s then
        print(line .. " = " .. s)
  else 
    print(line .. " = [variable not found]")
  end
end
```

but it's pretty fragile.

Note that I added `'` to the pattern.

The difficulty is that sometimes w is a string representing a name (key), and sometimes it's a string representing a number. In the second case it needs to be converted from string to number. But you need the context or some syntax to decide.

Here's the kind of fragility I mean:

```
>     data = {"math[pi]","AD['2']"}
>     
>     for i,line in ipairs(data) do
>>       s = getfield(line)
>>       if s then
>>             print(line .. " = " .. s)
>>       else 
>>         print(line .. " = [variable not found]")
>>       end
>>     end
math    table: 0x10ee05100
pi  nil
math[pi] = 3.1415926535898
AD  table: 0x10ee19ee0
'2' 2
AD['2'] = bar


> pi = 3
> math[3] = 42
>     data = {"math[pi]","AD['2']"}>
>     for i,line in ipairs(data) do
>>       s = getfield(line)
>>       if s then
>>             print(line .. " = " .. s)
>>       else 
>>         print(line .. " = [variable not found]")
>>       end
>>     end
math    table: 0x10ee05100
pi  3
math[pi] = 42
AD  table: 0x10ee19ee0
'2' 2
AD['2'] = bar
```

`math[pi]` is unchanged, but `getfield` interprets pi in the global context and gets `3` so the wrong field of `math` is returned.

Comment: See addendum on "the kind of fragility I mean..."

Comment: I can't come up with a scenario to make it fail.  I thought: AD = {[1] = 'foo', ['1'] = 'foobar', ['2'] = 'bar'} would do it, but still works..  What is the scenario?

Comment: One scenario I showed at the end of my answer is when a key has a value in _G. Then it's ambiguous whether to use the value of the key in _G, or the text of the key. The same problem can occur at the next level down in your table if you permit nesting tables.

Comment: What is the nested table scenario?

Comment: There may be no nested table scenario since the `loadstring` is always evaluated in _G.

Answer (score 0):

You'll get the strings `'1'` and `"'2'"`. You have to evaluate it to turn it into whatever object it is:

```
v = v[loadstring('return ' .. w)()]
```

Don't do this if the string came from an untrusted source though (like a user input or something) because they could execute arbitrary code.

Comment: attempt to index local `v' (a nil value)

Comment: @shaun5 it's a problem in your original code; you're setting `v` to `_G`, then setting it to an index of `_G`, then setting it to an index of the index, and by that time it becomes `nil`. What are you trying to do?